# Nth combinations ({a, b} = {b, a}) without repetition (enumeration / brute force)

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, combinations, combinatorics

I'm looking for an algorithm that generates the nth combinations without repetition.

I could find a lot on permutations where `(a, b) != (b, a)`, but I'm looking for combinations where `{a, b} = {b, a}`.

Example:

```
Set = {a, b, c}
n = 2
Combinations: {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c, d}
```

A generic, recursive implementation in Java that takes a Set or List would be great. I would also appreciate a link with a good explanation, pseudo or example code.

Comment: `n` is part of the input as well? So for `n=3`, you want to generate all combinations with three elements?

Comment: Yes, n is an input parameter. Maybe k would fit better. From a set with n elements I want all combinations with k elements. There should be "n choose k" combinations.

Comment: This can be solved with [combinatorial number system](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37736843/1090562)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following recursive method:

```
public static<T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> getPermutations (List<T> elements, int k) {
    return getPermutations (elements,k,0);
}

public static<T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> getPermutations (List<T> elements, int k, int i) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    if(k > 0) {
        int n = elements.size();
        for(int j = i; j <= n-k; j++) {
            T val = elements.get(j);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> tails = getPermutations(elements,k-1,j+1);
            for(ArrayList<T> tail : tails) {
                ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
                result.add(val);
                result.addAll(tail);
                results.add(result);
            }
        }
    } else {
        results.add(new ArrayList<T>());
    }
    return results;
}
```

You can then run it for instance with ([jDoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/TU)):

```
ArrayList<Character> set = new ArrayList<>();
set.add('a');
set.add('b');
set.add('c');

for(ArrayList<Character> element : getPermutations(set,2)) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
System.out.println("----------");
for(ArrayList<Character> element : getPermutations(set,3)) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
System.out.println("----------");

set.add('d');

for(ArrayList<Character> element : getPermutations(set,2)) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
System.out.println("----------");
for(ArrayList<Character> element : getPermutations(set,3)) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Which generates:

```
[a, b]
[a, c]
[b, c]
----------
[a, b, c]
----------
[a, b]
[a, c]
[a, d]
[b, c]
[b, d]
[c, d]
----------
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
[a, c, d]
[b, c, d]
```

---

The program works as follows: `k` is the number of elements we still have to pick, and `i` is the current offset value. Initially that offset value is `0`.

Now we iterate from `i` to `n-k` looking for potential candidates to be part of the head. Each element in that range will be the head for some combinations. We perform recursion on the remainder of the list. The recursion generates all the lists that take *k-1* elements on the remainder of the list. Then our job is simply to add a head in front and return the list.

You can implement this both faster and more memory conservative by using a special form of `LinkedList`s (which are common in logic and functional programming languages).

Comment: Looks good, I'll study it tomorrow. Is there a reason why you are returning a ArrayList and not List? I thought you should prefer the interface.

Comment: @MWin123: Indeed one better returns a `List`. This was only a *quick-and-dirty* solution and copy-pasting `ArrayList` everywhere is more efficient than writing `ArrayList` and `List`.... :P

Comment: It works fine but the memory use is pretty high. I tried storing the solutions outside of the method in a member variable and changing the return type to void. But I'm not sure how to make the recursive call. http://pastebin.com/M5DKdW4U

Comment: @MWin123: there is, as said in the answer, a way using head-tail lists, which will have a significant impact on the memory usage. I will try to implement that within a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

The recursive algorithm is easy:

1. Remove the first element.
2. Pair it with each other element in the list
3. Add that list to the list created by the remaining elements

Comment: Wouldn't that algorithm generate all permutations? I'm also not sure how I would implement that correctly.

Comment: @MWin123: I think a small modification is to *Pair it with each other element in the **remainder of the** list*

Answer (score 3):

Do you remember the problem of finding the [k-th permutations of the elements](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/ACM/Problems/Spring01/kthperm/kthperm.html)? Not a lot of people know the reason behind the algorithm, but it has a mathematical theory behind it. It can be solved by representing the number in [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Why am I talking about **k-th permutation** if the question was about finding **k-th combination**? Only because it can be solved with the similar mathematical theory. Surprise, surprise, there is a [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system):

> A k-combination of a set S is a subset of S with k (distinct)
>   elements. The main purpose of the combinatorial number system is to
>   provide a representation, each by a single number, of all
>   {\displaystyle {\tbinom {n}{k}}}  possible k-combinations of a set S
>   of n elements.

Read the article and most probably you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Given an input `list` and `n`, split `list` into the first item and the rest of the list calling them `head` and `tail`.  Then, the combinations you seek are:

- the combinations you can get from `tail` and `n`, plus
- the combinations you can get from `tail` and `n-1`, each with `head` prepended

If `n` is 0, the result is just one combination: {}

If `n` more than the size of `list`, the result is no combinations

---

Side note: For fun, I solved this in Haskell, putting the `n` = 0 case at the top:

```
comb 0 _ = [[]]
comb n (head:tail) | n > 0 = comb n tail ++ map (head:) (comb (n-1) tail)
comb _ _ = []
```